Docker run failing using python with parameters
I am trying to run a Python script with 1 mandatory parameter and 1 optional parameter and I am receiving this error message:
"docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create task for container: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: error during container init: exec: "2017": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown."

My command line:
docker run --rm -v /mnt/c/host_path1:/app/container_path1 -v  /mnt/c/host_path2:/app/container_path2 -v /mnt/c/host_path3:/app/container_path3 my_image 2017

My Dockerfile:
FROM python:3.11-slim

WORKDIR /app/src

COPY src/ /app/src

RUN pip install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host pypi.python.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org --no-cache-dir pandas pyodbc sqlalchemy

CMD ["python3", "my_main.py"]


I don't use environment variables, I did like tutorials, I access my parameters in code using sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2]. I am not understanding what I am doing wrong, I read tutorials, others stackoverflow links
PS1: when I not pass parameter 2017 in docker run, my script run OK
PS2: When I use ENTRYPOINT["python3","my_main.py"] I can pass 2017 in my run command line like above
Best regards,
Luis

Show us your dockerfile

@Paolo, Edited with the Dockerfile!

Anything you pass as the "command" part of the docker run command, after the image name, like the 2017, replaces the image's CMD.  You'd typically use this to run an alternate command, .e.g. docker run --rm -it my_image /bin/bash (a Celery worker is a common Python-oriented application of this too).

If you pass a command on the command line (when running the container) it will overwrite what you put in CMD.
This is why you can use ENTRYPOINT instead of CMD: In this case what you pass on the command line will be appended.
